# Joomla call function from template component with var

Tags: php, model-view-controller, function, joomla

I have this function in the model of my component:

```
public function getTotProperty($user){
       $database = &JFactory::getDBO();
       $database->setQuery("SELECT created_by  FROM #__jea_properties WHERE created_by=$user");
       $results = $database->loadObjectList();

       return $results;             
}
```

I need to call this function from template of the component. Without the var `$user`, it works:

```
echo $this->get('TotProperty');
```

But I need to pass the var `$user` in a function

Normally , the non Joomla method is  `getTotProperty($user);`

How can I pass the variable `$user` from the model to the template?

Comment: May be this can help you- https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/pull/336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the model first and then call the function directly on that. This should be done in the view:

```
$model = $this->getModel();
echo $model->getTotProperty($user);
```